# iOS UIView Rendering Issue: Incorrect Display of Rotated Mask After Rendering

Tags: ios, uiview

I tried to render the imageView in the CustomView, and found that the mask of the triangleView was not rendered correctly after rotation, and a part of it was not covered.

[The exception is shown in the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMPYE.jpg)

```
import UIKit

extension UIBezierPath {
    convenience init(triangleIn rect: CGRect) {
        self.init()
        let startX = rect.midX
        let startY = rect.minY
        let endY = rect.maxY
        self.move(to: CGPoint(x: startX, y: startY))
        self.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: endY))
        self.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: endY))
        self.close()
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let w: CGFloat = view.frame.width

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: w, height: w))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_2778")
        view.addSubview(imageView)

        let triangleView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: w/2, y: w/2, width: 100, height: 100))
        triangleView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        triangleView.transform = triangleView.transform.rotated(by: 0.523)

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(triangleIn: triangleView.bounds).cgPath
        triangleView.layer.mask = maskLayer

        imageView.addSubview(triangleView)

        let customView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: w + 10, width: w, height: w))
        customView.renderView = imageView
        view.addSubview(customView)
    }
}

class CustomView: UIView {
    var renderView: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        guard let renderView = renderView else { return }

        renderView.layer.render(in: context)
    }
}
```

I want the mask of the custom path to render normally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layers and Layer Masks do not auto-size when the view's frame changes size.

If we add an outlined, translucent yellow view "under" the triangle view, and update its frame when we rotate the triangle view, we can see (sort-of) what's happening...

First, without rotation transform:

[image]

then, after rotation transform:

[image]

Very quirky results, but evidently due to the way `UIView.layer.render(in: context)` works internally:

> This method renders directly from the layer tree, ignoring any animations added to the render tree. Renders in the coordinate space of the layer.

Depending on your ultimate goal and needs, one option is to use a `UIView` subclass for your triangle view, such as this (uses your `triangleIn rect:` UIBezierPath extension):

```
class MyTriangleView: UIView {
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass { CAShapeLayer.self }
    var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer { layer as! CAShapeLayer }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        shapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(triangleIn: bounds).cgPath
    }
    
}
```

then NO changes to your `CustomView` and only minor changes to your original `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        let w: CGFloat = view.frame.width
        
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: w, height: w))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "IMG_2778")
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        
        // use custom MyTriangleView
        let triangleView = MyTriangleView(frame: CGRect(x: w/2, y: w/2, width: 100, height: 100))
        triangleView.shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        
        triangleView.transform = triangleView.transform.rotated(by: 0.523)
        
        imageView.addSubview(triangleView)
        
        let customView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: w + 10, width: w, height: w))
        customView.renderView = imageView
        view.addSubview(customView)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]